# Replace string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is a PHP code example that contains the following snippet:

```
$data = array(
    'cKey1' => "dsfaasdfasdfasdfasdf",
    'cKey2' => "asdfasdfasdfadsfasdf",
    ...
);
```

Currently I'm just doing a `str_replace` on two hard-coded keys, but I need this to be more flexible now. These are the two regex I've come up with so far:

```
(?<=cKey1' => ).+(?=,)
(?<=cKey2' => ).+(?=,)
```

But, due to some people not using spaces, using double quotes, etc, this is not an ideal solution. Can someone point me in a better way to replace the values of `cKey1` and `cKey2` in a more efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: use the tokenizer. http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Comment: @anubhava: the output will be the same as the original string, just with made up values (similar to the example above) instead of real cKeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\K` (match reset feature):

```
$re = array("/'cKey1'\s*=>\s*\K[^,]*/", "/'cKey2'\s*=>\s*\K[^,]*/");

$repl = array('"foo"', '"bar"')

echo preg_replace($re, $repl, $str);
```

**Output:**

```
$data = array(
    'cKey1' => "foo",
    'cKey2' => "bar",
    ...
);
```

Comment: This almost did it for me. I get the contents of the code example using `file_get_contents()`, but I lose some of the opening lines for (likely due to the `<?php`). If I use `htmlspecialchars()` around `file_get_contents()` the data remains perfect, but your solution doesn't replace. Any ideas on that?

Comment: `string(478) " "2e73625b5179497a423434736e", 'cKey2' => "036289E99EA6A48CBDA1DB247E", 'file' => 'V2/api/autoDoc/exampleAPI2.0.1.php' ); ` You can see it cuts off the opening tag and `$data = array(`

Comment: `cat -vte V2/api/autoDoc/test.php
<?php$
^I$data = array($
^I^I'cKey1' => "2e73625b5179497a423434736e",$
^I^I'cKey2' => "036289E99EA6A48CBDA1DB247E",$
^I^I'file' => 'V2/api/autoDoc/exampleAPI2.0.1.php'$
^I);$
^I$`

Comment: yeah I'm not sure what is causing it.. The server the project is running on is 5.3, I tried it locally using mamp on 5.6 and the same thing happened. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104572/discussion-between-anubhava-and-matt-altepeter).

Answer (score 1):

Either use the tokenizer like @Casimir said or (if you insist on using a regex), you could come up with sth. like the following:

```
$regex = "~
            'cKey\d+'           # search for cKey followed by a digit
            .+?                 # match everything lazily
            ([\"'])             # up to a single/double quote (capture this)
            (?P<string>.*?)     # match everything up to $1
            \1                  # followed by the previously captured group
        ~x";
preg_match_all($regex, $your_string, $matches);
```

If you want to replace it with sth., consider using `preg_replace_callback()`, though you were not clear on your expected output.
See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wJ8vT0/2). Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for the clarification in the comments.

Comment: When you define the boundaries as double or single quotes you should rely on lazy dot matching, not on the negated character class. Also, `(\"|')` => `([\"'])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I value your feedback, so would you be so nice to say why using the lazy dot would be better in this case?

Comment: Check your regex with [`'cKey1' => "dsfaasdfasdfasd'fasdf",`](https://regex101.com/r/fX2sL8/1) input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks Wiktor, appreciated and updated.

Comment: I like capturing group based solutions more than those PCRE specific only since they are portable. Still, maybe there is no sense using `.+?` since it is sure there is `=>`.